# Set new objects to the array. Error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: arrays, swift

As far as i can see, it's quite a common mistake. However, I have not found a solution to my version of the problem. I want to add a list of new objects to an already created list based on the index. When I want to add each new Data object to the corresponding Sensor object by append(), I get this error: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value
However, I am unable to deal with this error. How to solve it?

function:

```
func setStationItemsWithData(addItemList: [AddItem], dataList: [Data]) {
    var dataItems = [DataItem]()
    var addItems = [AddItem]()
    addItems.append(contentsOf: addItemList)
    
    let addItemSensors = addItemList.flatMap{$0.sensors}
    
    dataList.forEach { data in
        guard let index = addItemSensors.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == data.id})
            else {
                print("Failed to find a Data for AddItem \(data.id)")
                return
        }
        let dataItem = DataItem(
            values: [ValueItem(
                date: data.values.first?.date ?? "",
                value: data.values.first?.value.value ?? 0.0)])
        
        dataItems.append(dataItem)
    
        addItems.compactMap{$0.sensors[index].data}.append(dataItem) !!!//here in .append() shows the error
    }
```

AddItem:

```
    class AddItem: Object, Identifiable {
    
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var stationId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var cityName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var addressStreet: String = ""
    var added = RealmOptional<Bool>()
    let sensors = List<SensorItem>()
    
    convenience init(id: Int, stationId: Int, cityName: String, addressStreet: String, added: RealmOptional<Bool>, sensor: [SensorItem]) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.stationId = stationId
        self.cityName = cityName
        self.addressStreet = addressStreet
        self.added = added
        self.sensors.append(objectsIn: sensor)
    }
    
    override class func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    }
    class SensorItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var stationId: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var param: ParamItem?
    @objc dynamic var data: DataItem?
    
    convenience init(id: Int, stationId: Int, param: ParamItem, data: DataItem) {
        self.init()
        self.id = id
        self.stationId = stationId
        self.param = param
        self.data = data
    }
  
}
class ParamItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var paramName: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var paramFormula: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var paramCode: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var idParam: Int = 0
    
    convenience init(paramName: String, paramFormula: String, paramCode: String, idParam: Int) {
        self.init()
        self.paramName = paramName
        self.paramFormula = paramFormula
        self.paramCode = paramCode
        self.idParam = idParam
    }
    
}
class DataItem: Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: Int = 0
    var values = List<ValueItem>()
    
    convenience init(values: [ValueItem]) {
        self.init()
        self.values.append(objectsIn: values)
    }
}
class ValueItem: Object {
    
    @objc dynamic var date: String? = ""
    @objc dynamic var value: Double = 0
    
    convenience init(date: String, value: Double) {
        self.init()
        self.date = date
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

Comment: you are discarding the result of your compactMap method and also trying to append a new element to it. Break it up into two lines. I am not sure where you want to store the result of your compactMap and/or append a new element.

Comment: I want to add new element (DataItem) to the SensorItem. Every single SensorItem should have one DataItem.